# EF 4.2 Code First, using an existing database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, code-first

Just trying to figure out if this has been solved or not.

I have a database (already created) and i want to let EF CF create the tables that are missing based on the models, is that possible?

I can't delete the database/create a new database for this, i just want it to maintain the tables based on the models).

Something like DropTablesIfModelChanges or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using **EntityFramework.SqlMigrations**

It is avaliable using [NuGet](http://nuget.org)

Scott Hanselman wrote a nice blog post about that.
[Entity Framework Code First Migrations](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/EntityFrameworkCodeFirstMigrationsAlphaNuGetPackageOfTheWeek10.aspx)

**hope this helps**